# IE10 CSS differing from chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Website in question: http://www.meyersboat.com/

Why does IE 10 do this compared to most other browsers are fine?

It seemingly works fine for http://www.meyersboat.com/meyers/

Chrome:

[image]

IE 10:

[image]

Comment: It's also broken in the latest Firefox.

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon examining your code, it's not working correctly in Firefox on OSX either:

```
<ul id="sub-navigation" style="display: block;">
    <li class="selected"><span><a href="javascript:void(0);">Welcome</a></span></li>
    <li style="width: 662px; margin-top: 28px;"></li>
</ul>
```

Try changing it to this:

```
<ul id="sub-navigation" style="display: block; position:relative;">
   <li class="selected"><span><a href="javascript:void(0);">Welcome</a></span></li>
   <li style="width: 660px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 18px;"> </li>
</ul>
```

1. We're setting the `<ul>` to `position:relative;` which let's us absolutely position the `<li>` elements within it's bounds.
2. We're then setting the second `<li>` to `position:absolute;` `top:18px;` `right:0px;`. This places the box exactly where it needs to be based on the bounds of the `<ul>` rather than using `margin-top:28px;`.
3. I've also adjusted the second `<li>` `width:662px;` to `width:660px;` which was breaking the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an empty `li` element? If it has no use just remove it.

If you do need this element, set its width to a little less than what it has now.

If you do need this specific width, I have a suggestion that might help:

change

```
#sub-navigation li a { padding: 2px 6px; }
```

To

```
#sub-navigation li a { padding: 2px 4px; }
```

Why? my guess is that it has something to do with the tiny differences every browser has that sometimes can express themselves with a different pixel here and there. Of course, I could be way wrong, but still, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The sibling LI has a fixed width and that is causing the issue. I removed the width property from the CSS rule and it aligns correctly:

[image]

[image]

This is a common mistake I see folks making with navigation related layouts, assuming a fixed # of pixels is consistent across displays, etc. That is why some of the folks reported FireFox not working correctly either. Chrome does seem to be a little different in this respect from what seems to be the actual specification. I say that cause it is normally reported it works in Chrome and not X Browser.

Another thing, you are using IE 9 compatibility mode. While your issue was not really an IE version issue, you should change that to edge from 9. This ensures your content is rendered using the most modern engine.

[image]

Also note I indicated your scripts are being loaded at the top of the markup, you should move your script tag to the bottom of your markup so your page loads and renders faster. Sorry Web Performance Optimization is a big deal to me and this is a simple thing to do.